# Drupal 7, show drupal blocks only on specific pages with PHP code?

Tags: commerce

I were working on drupal 7. In block configuration, under pages i went for an option 
"Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)"

Added the following code:

```
<?php
global $user;
$username=$user->name;
if($username=="admin")
{
   return TRUE;
}
else
{
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

It's shows me an error message at the top of the screen:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$name in eval() (line 3  of C:\xampp\drupal77\modules\php\php.module(75) : eval()'d code).

I don't know, how to fix it out. Please help me out.Thanks

Comment: I tested the code you show, and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

How the $username variable's value will be available there?
If you want to use current logged in user, write it like 
`global $user;`
and check `$user->name` instead of `$username`.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right you want to check for the admin user.

A possible code snippet would be:

```
global $user;
return $user->uid==1;
```

Of course you can check for any property of the $user object.

Comment: Hi, based upon user login...i needs to show the block (in sense return true or return false). Actual code, <?php global $user; $username=$user->user; checking with database, if count=1, returns true. Again am getting the same error. It's not solved.

Comment: The varialble $username is not defined in this context. All about the currently logged in user is in the global $user object.

Comment: hi thanks for your posting. See my error message "Undefined property: stdClass::$name" . The error message is not due to $username. please help me out.thanks